# How to create a variance-covariance matrix for forecasted fantasy basketball scores?

Tags: regression, variance, optimization, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have three basketball players who have played in games together and I want to find a Variance-Covariance matrix that will be as accurate as possible for their fantasy points in an upcoming game. My goal is to create a [multivariate-normal distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.html) (which requires a mean for each score and the variance-covariance matrix) that I can then sample.

My data looks like this:

```
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| game_number | player_a_score | player_b_score | player_c_score |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 1           | 15.2           | 12.3           | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 2           | 3.9            | 5.6            | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 3           | 10.22          | 9.9            | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 4           | 24.1           | 18.2           | -2.1           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 5           | 4.77           | 8.48           | 21.01          |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| 6(upcoming) | NULL           | NULL           | NULL           |
+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

I'm already using a statistical model to estimate the mean scores for game 6, but I also want a Variance-Covariance matrix that is as accurate as possible.

I understand that a Variance-Covariance matrix for my players should look like this:

```
+---+----------+----------+----------+
|   | A        | B        | C        |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| A | Var(A)   | Cov(A,B) | Cov(A,C) |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| B | Cov(B,A) | Var(B)   | Cov(B,C) |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
| C | Cov(C,A) | Cov(B,C) | Var(C)   |
+---+----------+----------+----------+
```

**Question 1** - What do I do about player C? They joined the team later in the season and have played less games with the other players. They may seem to have a highly negative correlation with the other players, but it could just be chance.

One possible solution would be to replace the covariance of a player with few games played with an average for the league for two position. For example, if `Player A` plays center and `Player C` plays point guard, I could take the average Cov between centers and point guards across the league and substitute it for Cov(A,C) until `Player C` has enough games for a significant result.

**Question 2** - Are there more accurate ways to assess variance? I feel like variance for a player could fluctuate due to other factors. For example, a player who is playing hurt could be expected to have a higher variance due to the possibility that they further injure themselves and get taken out of the game. Variance could also be effected by the opponent quality, if a team has a very good defense, maybe variance will be smaller due to less scoring.

I'm also modeling the scores via a statistical model, so maybe I could use a confidence interval from my model in some way? idk.

Thanks for reading this and thanks for the help!

Comment: The options you discuss, although related, concern different aspects of covariance.  Some of them concern some property that characterizes the team throughout the season; some concern properties that could vary over time; others concern relations between scoring and other factors.  Could you explain what characteristics of this team your covariance estimate is intended to reflect?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the response! I want to use this matrix to create a multivariate normal distribution with a predicted mean and then use that distribution to model different outcomes. So ultimately I want to get a variance-covariance matrix that is as accurate as possible for the next game.

Comment: In other words, it sounds like you want to forecast individual scores for the next game.  That's a different objective than suggested in your post.  Estimating a covariance matrix is a very small part of that process (and might not even be needed or appropriate).

Comment: @whuber Indeed, forecasting the mean score is an important part of my process and I'm already doing so, but I also need the variance-covariance matrix to create and sample the score distributions accurately.

Comment: How you go about doing that depends on the forecasting procedure.

Comment: @whuber Right now my forecasting procedure is using different predictor variables (home or away, past results, opponent quality, etc.) and using a gradient boosting random forest (xgboost) to predict my response variable `fantasy_points_scored`